Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 in Azure Functions Application
I have looked around a lot on this issue and turns out the problem is with the ConnectionString. I am using the below connection string and it works absolutely fine locally on my Azure Functions application but when I deploy it on Azure. I get this error:
2024-06-22T11:08:57Z   [Verbose]   Sending event Create
2024-06-22T11:08:57Z   [Verbose]   Sending exception event: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

For reference my connection string is:
Server=tcp:buzzats.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=buzzats;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ibraheem;Password=...;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

I have tried everything possible but I can't seem to fix this error. I am using Node JS v20 as my runtime for Azure Functions application. Here is below sample code of one HttpTrigger:
const { app, input } = require("@azure/functions");

const sql = input.sql({
    commandText: "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Students]",
    commandType: "Text",
    connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString",
});

app.http("getStudents", {
    methods: ["GET"],
    authLevel: "anonymous",
    extraInputs: [sql],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        try {
            const response = await context.extraInputs.get(sql);
            return { status: 200, body: JSON.stringify(response) };
        } catch (error) {
            return { status: 200, body: error.message };
        }
    },
});


I have looked all over StackOverflow, but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I am following the exact steps given on Microsoft site here

Check this SO answer and this link for the same error resolution.

This is my connection string stored in local.settings.json file:
"SqlConnectionString": "Server=tcp:buzzats.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=buzzats;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ibraheem;Password=...;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
How can I store that in your given format?

Can you share the error screenshot? Have you added the SqlConnectionString in the Azure Function app > Environment variables?

Can you check and share the SqlConnectionString in Azure Function app > Environment variables?

Please provide more details, the error occurred due to the connection string mismatch only in the Azure Function app in portal.

I ran the code successfully in both local and portal.

Can you share your error screenshot in the Azure function Invocations like this.

I tried to get the same error from my end and got it after changing the SqlConnectionString value in the Azure function app > Environment variables by adding a single quotation before the password. I got this error Logs.


Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index

The above error occurred due to the miss match of the SqlConnectionString value in the Azure Function app.
So, make sure the SqlConnectionString value is correct without any extra quotations in the Azure Function app Environment variables > App settings as shown below,
"SqlConnectionString": "Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=<db_name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<user_name>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"


Code :
const { app, input } = require("@azure/functions");

const sql = input.sql({
    commandText: "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Students]",
    commandType: "Text",
    connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString",
});

app.http("getStudents", {
    methods: ["GET"],
    authLevel: "anonymous",
    extraInputs: [sql],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        try {
            const response = await context.extraInputs.get(sql);
            return { status: 200, body: JSON.stringify(response) };
        } catch (error) {
            return { status: 200, body: error.message };
        }
    },
});

Output :
The function app ran successfully and got my db data in the Azure Portal as below.


I have verified multiple times, there is no additional quotes or anything in my connection string that is added in functions app env variables. Furthermore, the error which you are asking is exactly same as I have given in the original question at the top. My password doesn't have any special characters, it has only capital and small characters with some digits in it, which I don't think so should cause this issue but it does.

I cannot attach screenshots in the comments so I am attaching these links here: connection string

@IbraheemHaseeb Can you remove the connection string from the environment variables and try to add it again. Have you added the IP address of the function app in the SQL server> Networking or enabled allow access to all networks? Can you check and update it if not added. If the error still persists, try to deploy the code again from VScode and check.

Now it works, turns out, it was adding the connection string in the environment variable however it was supposed to add it into the connection strings section as shown here

Thank you so much for your help throughout this problem, means a lot seriously.

@IbraheemHaseeb Glad to know that your problem is resolved.
